# How can I keep track of object lists that reference each other in java?

Tags: java, tree, dynamic-arrays

I'm writing a java application that has users that create contracts. The contracts have a list of supporting users that can be added to the contract. The user that created this contract is not on the list of supporters. The supporting users can help the initial creator of the user follow through on the contract for example "No alcohol for 60 days."
I've got a function that can display the list of contracts in the user class.
I also can add users to a list in the contract.
How should I approach writing the viewSupportedContracts() function with the best memory issues in mind later on?
I will be using the User object in a main class.

```
package core;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Contract {
    private boolean termsAndAgreementSigned = false;
    private List<User> supporters = new ArrayList<User>();
    
    public Contract()
    {

    }

    public void setTermsAndAgreementSigned(boolean termsAndAgreementSigned) {
        this.termsAndAgreementSigned = termsAndAgreementSigned;
    }

    public boolean isTermsAndAgreementSigned() {
        return termsAndAgreementSigned;
    }

    public void addSupporter(User user)
    {
        supporters.add(user);
    }
    
    public void viewSupporters()
    {
        System.out.println("These are the supporters");
    }

}
```

```
package core;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class User {
    private List<Contract> contracts = new ArrayList<Contract>();
    
    public User()
    {
        
    }

    public void addContract(Contract contract) throws Exception {
        if(contract.isTermsAndAgreementSigned() == true)
            contracts.add(contract);
    }
    
    public List<Contract> getContracts() throws Exception {
        return contracts;
    }

    
    public void viewSupportedContracts() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Contract should also have an "owner" (the user that created the contract). I would have methods ``public List<User> getSupporters()`` to get the list of supporters, and ``public String getText()`` to get the text of the contract, and something like ``public User getOwner()`` to return the owner.

Comment: Contract having an owner is like contract having a head. This helps a lot thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your code to add contracts with users is very efficient in regards to memory and seems to me that you are looking for a way to view the contracts. My approach would be to implement a toString() method in the Contract class and either call toString on the List or write a for loop to print each Contract on a new line

```
public class Contract {
    public String toString() {
        return supporters.toString() + " users support you!";
    }
}

public class User {
    public String toString() {
        return "Create generated user text here";
    }

    public void viewSupportedContracts() {
        System.out.println(contracts.toString());        
    }
}
```

or

```
public void viewSupportedContracts() {
    for(Contract contract: contracts) {
        System.out.println(contract.toString());
    }        
}
```